# Where and why is the Royal Coat of Arms in the title sequence of 30Rock

Tags: title-sequence, 30-rock

During the opening title sequence of 30Rock we see various images around Rockerfeller Plaza including NBC studios and the building itself, there is a shot which looks identical to the [Royal Coat of Arms of the UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_coat_of_arms_of_the_United_Kingdom).

Where is this located, I don't remember seeing this when I visited the building a few years ago, also can some one tell me why it's there? Is there some British ancestry?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the replica of the Royal Coat of Arms as part of a panel called *Industries of the British Empire* sculpted by Carl Paul Jennewein at the [British Empire Building](http://wikimapia.org/4343053/The-British-Empire-Building) in Rockefeller Center, 620 5th Avenue.

[image]

Comment: So is this near 30 Rock? I'm not a US or NY native.

Comment: Yes, it's at Rockefeller Center. Sorry, I'll add that in.

Comment: Huh.. I never noticed that, or don't remember. I visited NY during Prince William's wedding so it was quite a few years ago, I do remember being called a M$therF$cker by a random stranger, getting a taxi ride with a guy who had tourettes and a bus journey from JFK to Manhattan where the bus driver winged a Lexus SUV, probably a typical day for most New Yorkers